# Need to space between two lines of Textview inside RecyclerView item

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, staggered-gridview

style.xml

```
 <style name="m_ui_medium_02" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
            <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
            <item name="android:lineSpacingExtra">-3dp</item>
            <item name="android:lineSpacingMultiplier">0.5</item>
            <item name="android:textColor">@color/ink_lightest</item>
```

[image]

Want to reduce space between highlighted two lines

Comment: can you add the xml code of the TextView

Comment: Adding style dynamically

Comment: <TextView
                android:id="@+id/answerText"
                style="@style/m_kpi_number_02"
                android:textColor="@color/ink"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/trackTitleText" />